# Python Selenium (waiting for a frame)

Tags: python, selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Selenium (waiting for frame, element lookups)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823272/python-selenium-waiting-for-frame-element-lookups)

I have these includes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Browser set up via

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
browser.get(loginURL)
```

However sometimes I do

```
browser.switch_to_frame("nameofframe")
```

And it won't work (sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't). Any way to force it to wait until it detects the frame?