# Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

How do I properly make it wait for a frame of a particular name to show up in python?

How do I make it wait for a website to load fully?

The documentation is vague to me and nothing seems to be working

Comment: can't you do following - import time
time.sleep(10)

Comment: Sleeps are usually not optimal because webpages may take longer than that to load fully. Also, sometimes you still want things to be as fast as possible (while fully loading).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Selenium (waiting for a frame)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827150/python-selenium-waiting-for-a-frame)

Answer (score 0):

The [selenium page on Python pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) has this in its code example:

```
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
```

Assuming the code is up to date, it appears the functionality you want isn't yet available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about waiting for an alert; I asked my question and the best answer that completely worked was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python?answertab=active#tab-top).

I think this is what you need, because you want to wait for a condition and sleep is not a good idea; you may wake too soon or too late.