# Python Selenium 2 API and wait until DOM is ready / element is visible

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like to wait until DOM is stable and the page is contructed until I try to execute Selenium WebDriver click() method.

Since Selenium 2 there doesn't seem to exist stock wait_for() method anymore. What's the best practice for "wait 15 seconds or until the element is clickable" style behavior with Selenium and Python 2?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823272/python-selenium-waiting-for-frame-element-lookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in ruby, i am sure it can be done in Python as well

```
@wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)
#You can define as many as you want with various times
@wait_less = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
#and then
@wait.until { @driver.find_element(:id, "Submit") }
@driver.find_element(:id, "Submit").click
```

Note  - You could wait for anything. other examples

```
@wait.until {@driver.window_handles.size > 1}
```

or

```
@wait_less.until {@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("Some text")}
```

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is is explicitly waiting. The Selenium documentation explains this further how [explicit waiting](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) works.

You can find different types of [expected conditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=expected_conditions#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) here. The condition which probably interests you the most is the one called 'visibility_of'.